# Reactor Flux proxy for Socket.IO-client Java

Tags: project-reactor, spring-webflux, socket.io-java-client

I'm implementing Spring WebFlux end-point that should get data from [Socket.IO-client Java](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java).

I don't understand the way to collect incoming data into Flux stream. Can I create new Flux some how and subscribe it to that incoming data? Thanks for advice.

```
@GetMapping("/streaming", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<MyRecourse> getStreaming() {

    URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost/socket.io"); // client
    Socket socket = IO.socket(uri);

    socket.on("event", args -> {    
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)args[0]; 
        MyRecourse recource = MyRecourse.create(obj);

        // how to put this recource into Flux stream?
    });

    return fluxStreamOfRecources;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Flux.create()](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#create-java.util.function.Consumer-) to generate a `Flux` from an event listener.

```
Flux.<MyResource>create(emitter -> {

     URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost/socket.io"); // client
     Socket socket = IO.socket(uri);

     socket.on("event", args -> {    
       JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)args[0]; 
       MyResource resource = MyResource.create(obj);
       emitter.next(resource);
     });

     // subscribe on error events
     socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, args -> {    
       // get error
       emitter.error(throwable);
     });

     // unsubscribe from events when the client cancels
     emitter.onDispose(() -> {
         // disconnect from socket
         // socket.off(...)
     });
 });
```